# I found evidence Hal Finney was working on Bitcoin (05 Jan 09) before v.0.1 was released (09 Jan 09). Is there any evidence he was involved earlier?

Tags: history

I found evidence Hal Finney was working on Bitcoin (05 Jan 2009) before v.0.1 was released (09 Jan 2009). Is there any evidence he was involved earlier?

https://web.archive.org/web/20090105145118/http://sourceforge.net/project/memberlist.php?group_id=244765

Comment: He must have generated his first address before 3 Jan since he received coins on that date: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2014/01/03/hal-finney-received-the-first-bitcoin-transaction-heres-how-he-describes-it/

Comment: @MCCCS: Please post an answer when you are answering the question. :)

Comment: Thats very cool. Cheers MCCCS :-D